# PHP prepare statement return null

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I am writting a php file to get all users in mysql database printed. My problem is that after prepare($sql) and $statement->execute, statement is always null. Here is my code:

```
public function selectAllUser(){
    $response = array();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Tata.users";
    $statement = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    if(!$statement){
        throw new Exception($statement->error);
    }

    //echo json_encode($statement);
    $statement->execute();





    try {
        throw new Exception($statement->error);
    } catch (Exception $e){}

    $result = $statement->get_result();
    //echo json_encode($result);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        //echo json_encode($row);
        $response[] = $row;
    }
    return $response;
}
```

This is the result I get if I do: echo $statement;

```
{"affected_rows":null,"insert_id":null,"num_rows":null,"param_count":null,"field_count":null,"errno":null,"error":null,"error_list":null,"sqlstate":null,"id":null}
```

This is the code where I am using this function:

```
$file = parse_ini_file("../../../Tata.ini");
$dbhost = trim($file["dbhost"]);
$dbuser = trim($file["dbuser"]);
$dbpass = trim($file["dbpassword"]);
$dbname = trim($file["dbname"]);

require ("secure/access.php");


$access = new access($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
$access->connect();

$users = $access->selectAllUser();
$access->disconnect();
echo json_encode($users);
```

Comment: If `$statement` is `null` before you execute, it won't execute, that's an error. If it's `null` after it's not something this code does. What errors do you get in your error log?

Comment: The problem is that if (!statement) is false which means statement is not null. I checked it with an else statement. Also connection has no problem

Comment: What does `var_dump($statement)` have to say?